# How to include image in frame from another html file?

Tags: javascript, html

i am currently having problem including image in frame from another file, what i am doing is creating a html page with two frame having code :

```
<html>

<frameset cols="20%,80%">
<frame src="aa.html" id="1">
<frame src="" id="2">

</frameset>

</html>
```

Then, in aa.html there are three links and on clicking the first link an image should open in frame with id="2".

```
aa.html

<html>

<head>
<link rel="import" href="cook.html">
<script>
function fun1()
{
    document.getElementById('2').src="b.html";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="fun1()">Home1</a>
<a href="fdsf">Hom2</a>
<a href="fdsf">Home3</a>
</body>

</html>
```

then b.html shows image in the frame,like this :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="ima.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But this does not work.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want in this way.

This function:

```
    function fun1() {
        document.getElementById('2').src="b.html";
    }
```

is working IN IFRAME, and not in MAIN WINDOW.
Try look at window.postMessage methods.

---

**UPDATE** working with window.postMessage look like that:

1) in child window will be function

```
  function fun1() {
   window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"id":2,"src":"b.html"}),'http://parent.window.com');
  }
```

2) in parent window, you should listen for this event, so add on start of page:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage( event )
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    return;
  try{
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      if( data.id != undefined && data.src != undefined ){
         document.getElementById(data.id).src = data.src;
      }
  } catch( exception ){ console.log( exception);}

}
```

Comment: can you give an example, and where to include the this script